# How to make clang stop before a specified LLVM pass and dump the LLVM IR

Tags: clang, llvm

How do I run clang and have it stop just before a pass, say `loop-vectorize`, and dump the IR to an `.ll` file that can be later fed to `opt`?

`opt` has a `-stop-after=` option, but Clang seems to be missing the equivalent option.  Here is a failed attempt with Clang 3.7.0rc2:

```
$ ../build/bin/clang -O2 -mllvm -stop-after=loop-vectorize a.cpp
clang (LLVM option parsing): Unknown command line argument '-stop-after=loop-vectorize'.  Try: 'clang (LLVM option parsing) -help'
clang (LLVM option parsing): Did you mean '-print-after=loop-vectorize'?
```

I've also tried running `clang -O0 -emit-llvm -S` and then running `opt -O2`, but the results were different than running `clang -O2` directly.

Comment: the correct option seems to be `-print-after=loop-vectorize`. but it is not recognizing loop-vectorize option.I get this *clang (LLVM option parsing): for the -print-after option: Cannot find option named 'loop-vectorize'`* error.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any way to stop after a specific pass when compiling with `Clang`, but instead I can offer a hopefully helpful alternative.

First, to address `opt` and `Clang` producing different IR files, it may be helpful to compare the pass lists for `clang -O2` and `opt -O2` manually. This can be done for both by passing `-debug-pass=Arguments`. When running Clang you will need `-mllvm` to pass the argument along.

Having done this myself it appears that a different set of passes are being run for each of them but I would suggest confirming for yourself.

To address your initial question, you might simply copy the list of passes run during `-O2` only up through `loop-vectorize` and simply run `opt` manually passing it the reduced list.